# Add assertions to List

Tags: c#, nunit, assertions

I have a list of assertions that will test my case. The tests will pass but I want to add them all to a list so that I can send that list to an xml file.

I did this with an xml file but any help on doing it this way? Here is the code I am using that does not work:

```
Assertions.Add(Assert.That(Resp.Cust.ID, Is.Not.Null));
```

**This is testing that the ID number from the response is not null, and I am using Nunit**

Comment: Sorry, but what is it that you're trying to send to the xml. Is it the description of the assertion so that you have something like a test case document?

Comment: I am sending the actual assertion data and then if it passed or not...so true or false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assert.That returns void, which means you cannot add anything to list of assertions. On the other hand, you can add constraint to list, 'Is.Not.Null', and object argument, like this:

```
Assertions = new List<Tuple<object, IResolveConstraint>>();
Assertions.Add(Tuple.Create((object)Resp.Cust.ID, Is.Not.Null));
```

And then test each assertion like this:

```
foreach (var pair in Assertions)
{
  Assert.That(pair.Item1, pair.Item2);
}
```

If you need results of testing in your xml file, you can test your assertions like this:

```
object value = ...
IResolveConstraint expr = ...
Constraint constraint = expr.Resolve();
var result = constraint.Matches(value);
```